# mysql using sum for a column to get total amount for each group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, cumulative-sum

This is data in table **orders**.

Does anyone can help me to do the statistics work?

```
-------------------------------
id  | order_amount | createtime
-------------------------------
1   |    10        | 1513605522
2   |    20        | 1513605523
3   |    30        | 1513605524
4   |    40        | 1513605525
-------------------------------
```

This is the output what I need

```
-------------------------------
 total_income | createtime
-------------------------------
    10        | 1513605522
    30        | 1513605523
    60        | 1513605524
   100        | 1513605525
-------------------------------
```

this is my sql statement, it doesn't give me what i want.

```
select sum(order_amount) as total_income from order group by create time;
```

BTW. Is it possible to produce the output....
Any help means a lot to me. Many thanks.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Something like "error 1064 , syntax error"?

Comment: it shows no error at all, but the value in total_income is different

Comment: Just be careful naming a table 'order', notice that the answer below names the table 'orders' (with an -s) so that it's not confused with the SQL keyword ORDER, as in ORDER BY.

Comment: oops, i didn't notice that, the 'order' is really not a valid name for tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do this using a correlated subquery:

```
select o.*,
       (select sum(o2.order_amount)
        from orders o2
        where o2.createtime <= o.createtime
       ) as running_amount
from orders o;
```

Another option -- using non-standard SQL -- is to use variables:

```
select o.*, (@s := @s + o.order_amount) as running_amount
from (select o.*
      from orders o
      order by createtime
     ) o cross join
     (select @s := 0) params;
```

Note that the subquery is only needed in the more recent versions of MySQL.

Actually, MySQL 8.0 *finally* supports window functions, so it can be done using standard SQL in that version:

```
select o.*, sum(o.order_amount) over (order by o.createtime) as running_amount
from orders o;
```

Comment: Doesn't window function need something like `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`?

Comment: It works like a charm,Bro. I just tried first solution.

Comment: @MatBailie . . . The window frame clause should be optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
set @amt := 0;
select @amt := @amt + order_amount as total_income, createtime
from order
order by createtime asc;
```

Comment: The statement looks tidy and it works as well. Thanks, buddy